# CloudantDB: Grant database permissions

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I want to add more users to access my cloudantDB API. On permissions tab, I add the username to Grant permission field with any username but I don't know the password. 
[image]

Could we can get password by using Grant Permission? I know we need both username and password to access cloudant API. Please give me your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API key with password on the same page in the Cloudant dashboard (just below Grant database permissions) that you can share with others to access your database.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I want to create the login function demo by using API cloudantDB, I cannot share the key API and password to user. It's very complex and hard to remember.

Comment: There are only two options that you have here I am afraid, 1) share with a user as you described. The user can then use the API with their own password, and 2) as I described above.